# Adding Request response to separate rows in Pandas Dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I'm trying to add the request response to a dataframe and then eventually a csv. The data is nested and I've tried what I've learned about getting this data but so far it's not working.

The data is being put in one row and in one column. In the JSON below I need to get each of the lists on to its own row in the dataframe.

```
import requests
import json
import csv
import pandas as pd
from ast import literal_eval
import time
from pprintpp import pprint as pp

market_symbols = []
candleInterval = ''

def get_candle(marketSymbol):
      
    candle_url = f'https://api.kraken.com/0/public/OHLC?pair={marketSymbol}&interval=5'
    candle_data = requests.get(candle_url)
    bytes_value = candle_data.content
    my_json = bytes_value.decode('utf8').replace("'", '"')
    data = (json.loads(my_json))
    data['symbol'] = marketSymbol

def make_df(data):
    
    df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=['error','result','last', 'symbol']).explode('result')
    #df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=['error','result','last', 'symbol'])
    #df[['1', '2', '3', '4']] = pd.DataFrame(df['result'].tolist()).to_numpy()
    #put list values into own columns
    ticker_df = pd.DataFrame(df['result'].tolist())
    unnested_df = pd.concat([
        pd.DataFrame(ticker_df[x].tolist()).add_prefix(f'{x}_') 
        for x in ticker_df
    ], axis=1)

    df = pd.concat([df, unnested_df], axis=1).drop('ticker', axis='columns')
    cols = ['1', '2', '3', '4','5', '6', '7', '8' ]
    fdf = df[cols].copy()
    fdf.columns =['1', '2', '3', '4','5', '6', '7', '8' ]  
    pp(fdf)
    return data    


if __name__ == "__main__":

    period_time = 59.8# set it to seconds
    candle_symbols = ['XBTUSD', 'ADAUSD']
    
    
    while True:
        for symbol in candle_symbols:
            tick_data = get_candle(symbol)
            df = make_df(tick_data)           
            
        time.sleep(period_time)
```

result:

```
{
    'error': [],
    'result': {
        'XXBTZUSD': [
            [
                1613364300,
                '46578.3',
                '46900.0',
                '46578.3',
                '46900.0',
                '46795.1',
                '16.26216021',
                202,
            ],
            [
                1613364600,
                '46900.0',
                '47057.7',
                '46812.3',
                '46922.6',
                '46929.4',
                '48.17195344',
                275,
            ],
                     [
                1613580000,
                '51077.7',
                '51111.0',
                '51077.7',
                '51111.0',
                '51093.8',
                '0.86585941',
                51,
            ],
        ],
        'last': 1613579700,
    },
    'symbol': 'XBTUSD',
}
```

Comment: what is the desired output, could you share a sample df